# Should I use a many-to-many associative table from a third table?

Tags: database, database-design, many-to-many

I am implementing a messaging system.
I have these tables: `Thread`, `User`, `ThreadUser`, `Message`

- Each `Thread` has many `User`s, via `ThreadUser` (many-to-many)
- Each `User` has many `Thread`s, via `ThreadUser` (many-to-many)
- Each `Message` belongs to a `Thread` (many-to-one)
- Each `Message` belongs to a `User` (many-to-one)

Is it a good idea to have `Message.from` point to `ThreadUser` instead of `User`, to ensure that messages in a thread can only be from a user in that thread and not any user in my DB? What are the downsides?

Comment: Would like to ask a question for clarification as well as to be sure that I understand this right, please... What's the nature of Many-to-Many relationship between Threads and Users? Can a thread, say, `Thread 1` be associated with `User 1` and `User 2` at the same time?

Comment: Yup, many users are involved in a thread

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I feel should be a reasonable solution to your problem:

**User Table:**

`UserId (PK), UserName, Email, ......`

**Threads Table:**

`ThreadId (PK), ThreadName, ......`

**ThreadUser Table:**

`ThreadUserId (PK), ThreadId(FK), UserId(FK),........`

Please remember to make a composite `UNIQUE KEY` of `(ThreadId, UserId)` in this table, thereby ensuring that each user can only participate once in a thread.

Finally,
 **Messages Table:**

`MessageId (PK), ThreadUserId(FK), MessageTitle, MessageBody,........`

Please note that we identify **both** the `Thread` and the `User` by referncing `ThreadUserId` in the messages table. So that should help in identifying which message was posted by which user and under which thread.

This means, before someone posts anything in `Messages`, the application will have to validate whether a `ThreadUserId` exists for that `User` and for the `Thread` that they're wishing to write something in.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I would drop `ThreadUserId`, use `ThreadId, UserId` as PK in `ThreadUser`, include `ThreadId` and `UserId` in `Messages`, and make a composite FK constraint to reference those columns in `ThreadUser`. It means one less meaningless domain, and you can join directly from `Messages` to `User` or `Threads`.